# getting the object passed to the NSThread selector

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios4, nsthread

When I'm creating an NSThread I pass it a number that I want the process to be aware of. I can understand how to set the number but I cannot figure out how to read the number from the thread selector method so that I can then pass it to a timer.

How do you do it?

```
-(void) setthread
{
```

//passing the number to the selector here fine

```
NSThread* timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startTimerThread) object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];/
    [timerThread setThreadPriority:0.5];
    [timerThread start]; //start the thread 

}
```

// don't get how to read the value passed to this selector

```
-(void) startTimerThread
{


    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                      target: self
                                    selector: @selector(timerTick:)
                                    userInfo: thenumberhere
                                     repeats: YES] retain];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying your selector wrong:

```
@selector(startTimerThread)   // we are missing ':' at the end
```

It should have `:` at the end, like so:

```
@selector(startTimerThread:)
```

This indicates it's a selector which takes one parameter.

Then take in the parameter in your `startTimerThread` method:

```
-(void) startTimerThread:(NSNumber *)myNumber {
    // ... etc
```

Comment: This answer just helped me for a similar problem. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

that will not work..
this will:

```
NSThread* timerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startTimerThread:) object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];


-(void) startTimerThread:(NSNumber *)thenumberhere
{


    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                      target: self
                                    selector: @selector(timerTick:)
                                    userInfo: thenumberhere
                                     repeats: YES] retain];

    [runLoop run];
    [pool release];
}
```

you 'forgot' to add the object, that you pass along with the selector as a parameter, to the method you implemented.

Comment: why to use NSRunLoop??

Comment: I adapted, more than a year ago, the code that was given with the question. Ask dubbeat.